# Error adding significance levels in ggplot boxplot after changing the stats table

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, ggpubr

I am trying to add significance levels to a geom_boxplot by using stats_pvalue_manual. Since I have a 12-level factor I ordered the data by mean size. I only keep the significant comparisons that are closest to each other. If I use the stats table everything works (but looks horrible).

```
dput(pl[1:4,])
structure(list(rating = c(0, 1, 0, 2), lang2 = structure(c(5L, 
10L, 7L, 8L), levels = c("KLIN", "NAVI", "DOTH", "KHUZ", "ATLA", 
"ADUN", "KESH", "ORCI", "UIUI", "VULC", "SIND", "QUEN"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is what works:

```
stat_pvalue <- pl %>% 
 rstatix::wilcox_test(rating ~ lang2) %>%
 filter(p < 0.001) %>% 
 rstatix::add_significance("p") %>% 
 rstatix::add_y_position(fun="mean") %>% 
 mutate(y.position = seq(min(y.position), max(y.position),length.out = n()))
```

A tibble: 53 × 12

## #    .y.    group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic         p     p.adj p.adj.signif p.signif y.position groups

## #

1 rating KLIN   NAVI     751   751   218406. 9.95e- 15 3.18e- 13 ****         ****           1.40 <chr [2]>
2 rating KLIN   DOTH     751   753   161834. 1.85e- 48 9.62e- 47 ****         ****           1.75 <chr [2]>
3 rating KLIN   KHUZ     751   750   142862. 1.34e- 63 7.64e- 62 ****         ****           2.10 <chr [2]>
4 rating KLIN   ATLA     751   747   143668. 3.14e- 62 1.73e- 60 ****         ****           2.45 <chr [2]>
5 rating KLIN   ADUN     751   751   135155  2.22e- 70 1.29e- 68 ****         ****           2.80 <chr [2]>
6 rating KLIN   KESH     751   754   119372  1.3 e- 86 7.8 e- 85 ****         ****           3.15 <chr [2]>
7 rating KLIN   ORCI     751   749   117751  4.57e- 87 2.79e- 85 ****         ****           3.51 <chr [2]>
8 rating KLIN   UIUI     751   755   106752  2.94e-100 1.85e- 98 ****         ****           3.86 <chr [2]>
9 rating KLIN   VULC     751   749    95561  1.11e-111 7.1 e-110 ****         ****           4.21 <chr [2]>
10 rating KLIN   SIND     751   751    87589  2.64e-121 1.72e-119 ****         ****           4.56 <chr [2]>

```
ggplot(pl, aes(x=lang2, y=rating)) + geom_boxplot() +
  ggpubr::stat_pvalue_manual(stat_pvalue, label = "p.signif") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

[Boxplot with significant differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5crD.png)

Then I just keep the comparisons that are close together, i.e. the first significant difference per factor level

```
stat_value2 <- stat_pvalue %>% group_by(group1) %>% slice_head(n=1)

stat_value2
#
```

A tibble: 10 × 12

## Groups:   group1 [10]

.y.    group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic        p    p.adj p.adj.signif p.signif y.position groups
                                       
1 rating ADUN   UIUI     751   755   255755  7.9 e- 4 1.1 e- 2 *            ***           15.5  <chr [2]>
2 rating ATLA   KESH     747   754   242381  1.81e- 6 3.26e- 5 ****         ****          13.3  <chr [2]>
3 rating DOTH   ADUN     753   751   242065  8.64e- 7 1.73e- 5 ****         ****           8.78 <chr [2]>
4 rating KESH   VULC     754   749   252550  2.84e- 4 4   e- 3 **           ***           16.9  <chr [2]>
5 rating KHUZ   KESH     750   754   243727  2.15e- 6 3.66e- 5 ****         ****          11.2  <chr [2]>
6 rating KLIN   NAVI     751   751   218406. 9.95e-15 3.18e-13 ****         ****           1.40 <chr [2]>
7 rating NAVI   DOTH     751   753   221564. 1.29e-13 4   e-12 ****         ****           5.26 <chr [2]>
8 rating ORCI   SIND     749   751   230356  5.86e-10 1.41e- 8 ****         ****          17.9  <chr [2]>
9 rating UIUI   SIND     755   751   239677  1.09e- 7 2.29e- 6 ****         ****          18.6  <chr [2]>
10 rating VULC   SIND     749   751   248230. 5.5 e- 5 8.8 e- 4 ***          ****          19.3  <chr [2]>

Then I get the following error message for the figure

```
ggplot(pl, aes(x=lang2, y=rating)) + geom_boxplot() +
    ggpubr::stat_pvalue_manual(stat_value2, label = "p.signif") +
    theme_bw(base_size = 16)
```

Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `label = as.character(data %>% pull("p.signif"))`.
✖ `label` must be size 1, not 10.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: group1 = "ADUN".
Backtrace:

1. ggpubr::stat_pvalue_manual(stat_value2, label = "p.signif")
2. dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)

I am at a total loss here. I found the lines in the code but I cannot figure out what changed. Help would be very much appreciated.

I tried to change the order of group1 and also the aesthetics of the figure but nothing worked.

Comment: share your data with `dput(yourdata)` so we can help further

Comment: @Mike: the dataset is very long, so I just show the first 4 rows.